# iOS instagram api can't login( Suspicious login Attempt )

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, instagram-api

I am doing login with instagram for over two years ,recently suddenly start to show message : Suspicious login Attempt ( we detected an unusual login attempt ) so no body can login now

the weird thing, I have same code with same app at android but it works fine , the problem show up at iOS only

please any help ?

note : I am using official Instagram API from their website .
I login by webview

Comment: I think you were using unofficial API, so don't expect any support.

Comment: @VahidAmiri no, I am using the official one , from instagram website itself

Comment: @VahidAmiri We are also facing the same issue with official login using email. But working with fb.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue with an app that had been working for over a year

Comment: hey @Fr4nz I couldn't solve this problem , but I did something to make the users able to login after they insert the secure code , if you want that solution, I will share the code with you

Comment: Yes please I'd be interested to see what you did

Comment: Hey @Ali Ayasrah, interesting to hear you found a solution. Would you be able to share it with us? We've had the same issue affect our apps and would love to find a fix.

Comment: sorry I was traveling , did't answer you 
it seems instagram solved the problem , still you have it ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been resolved by Instagram in the last few days.

Discovered it was working again this morning when testing a potential workaround.